# Create Rating starts in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, web-deployment

I am new to the django, and I am working on a data science project that aims to create a web application that interact with user in order to gather same data in first step, and after that, make a recommendation to the user. 
My issue is that I have a model `Countries` that has `country_name`, `user_rating`, and `user_id` as `ManyToMany` fields, how I can give the user the choice to rate country name using the stars rating and then save the rating in `user_rating` field ?

Comment: You can use a `Stars` widget: https://pypi.org/project/django-starfield/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**django-starfield** package [PyPi]](https://pypi.org/project/django-starfield/) to use the `Stars` widget. You can install this - for example in your local environment, with:

```
pip3 install django-starfield
```

then you can use this in your form, like:

```
from django import forms
from django_starfield import Stars

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    user_rating = forms.IntegerField(widget=Stars)
```

Comment: how I can increate the size of stars and to rate should start from the left to right

Comment: @AyoubELMAJJODI You can override the `stars.html` template with your own, or add CSS styling. Every rating widget gets a specific `id` (just use your favourite browser's inspector to discover it).

Comment: if user_rating is a field
and I want to change it using widget.
How should I write it?